# Ngrok windows autostart

Tags: windows, autostart, ngrok

How can i autostart ngrok on Windows ? Scheduled tasks command do not work.

`schtasks /create /tn "start" /sc onstart /delay 0000:30 /ru system /tr "C:\ngrok-stable-windows-amd64\ngrok.exe http 80"`

Comment: Did you find the answer? 
By «autostart» do you mean at boot time or at user login time ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a text file with the command you want to run. Save it as a bat file in the same folder as the ngrok exe file. Create a shortcut of the bat file in the windows startup folder (Windows Key + R, type shell:startup).